# set switch to trigger custom filter in asp.net mvc for exception handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

is there something I need to "turn on" to allow my asp.net mvc application to utilize custom exception filters?

I posted in here last week with code samples to a custom filter I wrote that should catch and handle a custom exception but for some reason I keep getting an error on my throw line indicating that the exception was not handled by user code.

I had a response last week from someone who indicated they copied and pasted my code exactly and it worked fine for them.  This makes me wonder if maybe I need to set something web.config or something to tell the app to use the custom filter for unhandled exceptions.

please advise,
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you implementing?  If you inherit from FilterAttribute and IExceptionFilter class/interface, you will have to ensure the exception content has the exceptionhandled flag set to true to prevent the error, I believe.

Comment: as it turns out, I'm only seeing the error when I go to debug mode and use the casini (sp) web server.  If I 'view in browser' I do not see the error.  So I'm thinking it must be a debug setting in VS?  Is there anyway to cut those down so it allows the desired output while debugging?